# How to enable remote connections for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I enable remote connections on an SQL Server 2008 installation?

I have created a rule in the windows firewall to allow traffic through port 1433, but that does not seem to be enough.

Comment: Hmmm.....even after following all the tips in this, I still can't connect to my SQL server remotely!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL Server Configuration Managaer

- SQL Server Network Configuration

  - Protocols for MSSQLServer
  - Enable TCP/IP

Also in SQL server Mgmt Studio on the server

- Right click the server
- Properties
- Connections
- Make sure "Allow remote connections to this server" is checked

Comment: Spot on! That worked! :)

Comment: Other think that should should see is of the Broker Service is ON.

Comment: The TCP/IP was what was giving me the issues! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If it's a named instance, you'll also want to set the TCP/IP port to a static value and enable that in the firewall. Otherwise it's a dynamic port, meaning it could change over time.

Comment: You'll also want a static port if you're using impersonation as the delegation trusts require a port number when set up in AD.

Comment: Actually, if you want to use Kerberos in any capacity, to include just authentication.