# Remote connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I have a problem connecting with a remote Microsoft SQL Server 2008

I have tried this: [How to enable remote connections for SQL Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7798/how-to-enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-2008)

so the remote connection checkbox is checked at the database properties and in the SQL Server Configuration Manager is the TCP/IP enabled.

In the Windows Firewall I added a rule to give my public ip full access and I also configured 1433 to be open with this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

here is my error: (sorry for having a dutch error)
[image: my sql management studio error]

I even enabled `Named pipes` in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. But that didn't help either. How can I see if this is an Windows Firewall issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved by running this `*.bat` file: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.