# Cannot access SQL 2008 or 2012 R2 Express server remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried to remotely access two different servers on two different machines, one 2008 the other 2012, and have had zero luck with either machine.

I have followed the steps in: [How to enable remote connections for SQL Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7798/how-to-enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-2008/7801#7801)

1. I went to the protocols for MSSQLServer and enabled TCP/IP making sure the dynamic port was blank and the IPALL TCP port is 1433.
2. I checked the properties of the server and confirmed under Connections  that remote connections to the server are allowed.
3. I went to the firewall and added a rule allowing local port 1433 for all profiles. I even tested the connection with the firewall disabled.

None of these steps worked for either machine. I can see and access all the machines' shared files on the network. I'm not sure what to try next. This is my first time trying to setup a sql server. I appreciate any help or advice you can give me!

Answer (score 3):

You have to restart the SQL Server service in `services.msc` after making these changes for them to take effect. Restart them and try again. Also, if you're using a named instance instead of the default instance, make sure you include that in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Neither option seemed to solve my problem though.

I had restarted the computer previously. I just tried restarting the SQL server in Services with no luck.

I am using "ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS" as the server name.